# ADODB multiuser overwriting data

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have database in MS Access 2016, and run update query thru Excel VBA. Sometimes several users can perform this operation at the same time and then overwrite their data when they shouldn't because of condition in UPDATE statement.

How to block data overwriting?

When I open the table in Access there is a few seconds delay between run query in VBA and the information in the table. Maybe this delay is the problem and it can be eliminated somehow?

Database is divided to FE and BE and connection is persistent.

My query:

```sql
UPDATE 
(SELECT TOP 1 ID, Col1, Update_time, Update_user 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Update_user Is Null 
ORDER BY Col2 DESC , ID)  AS U_ROW 
SET U_ROW.Update_time = Now(), U_ROW.Update_user = [username];
```

In Excel VBA I run it thru ADODB.Command:

```vb
With baseRecordsetCommand
    .ActiveConnection = objectConnection
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "qryTest"
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@username", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Username)
    .Execute recordsAffected
End With
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data to illustrate why `UPDATE` condition is not adhered? Please show a before and after sample for first and second user when `UPDATE` runs. Testing on my end, unless new rows are added, `UPDATE` should only update a single record the first time and zero records thereafter since `Update_user Is Null` will no longer hold for next user(s).

Comment: Why is Excel involved?

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with the `LockType ` property set on the `Recordset`. If you have it set `adLockBatchOptimistic`, then it is a free-for-all when it comes to updates. You probably want to use the `adLockPessimistic` LockType. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/locktypeenum?view=sql-server-ver15 for more info.

Comment: @Parfait problem is only when users run query in the same time. When difference is more then 3 seconds it works fine. So I think that data is good.

Comment: @June7 because not every user have Office Professional with MS Access or MS Access Runtime and instaling it is a problem.

Comment: @rickmanalexander I run it thru `Command` not `Recordset`. I can't set `LockType` of `Command`. But I tested locking in debug mode and it works fine. I added code to transaction and record is locked until I commit.